# Ketones and nucleophilicity

Tags: organic-chemistry

Is there anyone who can give me a convincing argument about the ketone, or the carbonyl oxygen in the ketone being nucleophile or not? . I really don't know what to write anymore. Everyone says something different. My instructor said that the Ketone oxygen can be protonated, thus reacting as a nucleophile. Others says that  Protonating the ketone in fact makes it more electrophilic.

Here is the molecule I'm working with (attached) and I have to mention all the nucleophilic sites - I've done that. This is the only one that really is confusing me. Hoping for some clarification.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ9qD.jpg

Answer (score 1):

> Everyone says something different

Well, actually they don't. A ketone has a nucleophilic and an electrophilic center. The carbonyl carbon is electrophilic and can be attacked by nucleophiles, the oxygen itself can act as a nucleophile and can, for example, be protonated. And yes, if we protonate the oxygen the "ketone", or better the carbonyl carbon, get's more electrophilic.

An example would be the [Luche reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luche_reduction). In this case the carbonyl oxygen coordinates to cerium chloride, thus acting as nucleophile, and makes the carbonyl carbon even more reactive towards nucleophiles.

Comment: Thank you the explaining this. It makes more sense now. However, I don't have this reaction the my textbook (The Luche reduction). Do you know any other more common kind of reactions to be used in this situation?

Comment: As I have to indicate a reaction regarding this nucleophilic site.

Comment: Well, I've linked the wikipedia article so you can look it up there. Another example would be the acid catalyzed synthesis of ketals. Or the acid calayzed formation of Cyanhydrine ( https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanhydrine ) , which is actally quite interesting since you can use lithium salts instead of acids to catalyze that. Li+ acts quite similar to H+.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answers, DSVA! Now it makes more sense and I can carry on with my assignment.